# What does netbeans or any IDE look for when importing a project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I tried to use a project not made using netbeans. I tried to use it by creating a new project and using the "web application with existing resources". When browsing for the existing project, I clicked on the project name and clicked OK, but it opens the project and shows the list of folders in the project and doesn't accept the projectnamefolder as the project to be imported.

What does an IDE look for the identify a project as a project that can be imported

Comment: depends on the type of project you try to import. a Java project? a maven project? ..

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse looks for .project files when importing existing eclipse projects. If you create an eclipse project for existing code, you can simply create a project and point it to the right folder, and specify the layout for source and target.

Comment: not necessarily. it will generate them if they're not there.

Comment: Edited to differentiate between import/create new project.